Expo NativeWind styling not working properly?
I`m novice to React Native and I'm trying to style some of components using classes. I have installed NativeWind for expo using this manual: https://www.nativewind.dev/quick-starts/expo
But when I'm changing class name some strange is happening.
<Text className="text-2xl">Fofo</Text>

For this line of code everything works well, the text increases its size.
But when I enter the following line of code:
<Text className="text-2xl text-[#ECADFF]">Fofo</Text>

Everything stops working and no styles are applied. For the following line of code the situation is the same
<View className="bg-red"></View>

The component does not change its background at all.
Are there some ways to fix this?
